# knockout.js - How to add a class name to an element

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to generate a 3 level navigation using knockout.js. From the static template of the navigation I have the information, that the class ul.withsubdrop for the 2nd ul element should only be set, if there is a 3rd submenu present, otherwise not. How can I do that, since I evaluate, the existence of a 3rd level menu much later in the code? Can you point me into the right direction? Thank you.

```
<!-- LEVEL 1 -->
<ul data-bind="foreach: entries">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: title"></a>


        <!-- LEVEL 2 -->
        <!-- ko with: $data.menu -->
        <ul class="withsubdrop" data-bind="foreach: entries">
            <li>
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: title"></a>


                <!-- LEVEL 3 -->
                <!-- ko with: $data.menu -->
                <ul data-bind="foreach: entries">
                    <li><a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: title"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /ko -->


            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /ko -->


    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    $.getJSON("/rest/menu/1.0/json", function(allData) {
        ko.applyBindings(ko.mapping.fromJS(allData));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us where it should go?  You have a lot of html there and it is confusing to read

Comment: I simplified the code, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer isn't terrible but if it is strictly presentation logic I would not move it to the View Model.

```
<!-- LEVEL 1 -->
<ul data-bind="foreach: entries">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: title"></a>
        <!-- LEVEL 2 -->
        <!-- ko with: $data.menu -->
        <ul class="" data-bind="foreach: entries, css: { 'withsubdrop': menu().entries().length > 0 }">
            <li>
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: title"></a>
                <!-- LEVEL 3 -->
                <!-- ko with: $data.menu -->
                <ul data-bind="foreach: entries">
                    <li><a data-bind="attr: {href: url}, text: title"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can see I added a css binding on the ul at level 2 that checks if the menu().entries has a value greater than zero.  Of course I am assuming menu is an observable and entries is an observable array.

Also keep in mind that you don't need to use the $data binding in your view like you are as that is already the scope being set.  Usually you would use $data when you are binding directly on to the existing scope and not identifying a property of that scope.

Comment: This is a better answer, as the question does seem to be strictly presentation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, unfortunatly it does not work with my code, I am getting ReferenceError ko is not defined and menu is not defined. Maybe there are some errors within my code? I updated my inital question and added the javascript code. I am using the mapping plugin. I also intentionally using $data.menu, since I was getting errors without it, as the JSON does not always return a menu property, if there is no 2nd or 3rd level navigation. Should I better try and build the model myself, instead of using the mapping plugin? Is the problem, I have related to the mapping plugin?

Comment: The reference ko is not defined means knockout is not working on your page at all.  It just means you aren't loading knockout.  The menu is not defined error would be in your view model.  Those are separate questions though and very basic and easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

In your JavaScript, have a thirdSubmenuPresent boolean field.

In your HTML, you databinding will look like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="foreach: entries, css: { withsubdrop: thirdSubmenuPresent }" role="menu">
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please elaborate a bit more on how I can do that? I am right now fully relying on the knockout mapping plugin, so my javascript is just this: $.getJSON("/rest/menu/1.0/json", function(allData) {
    ko.applyBindings(ko.mapping.fromJS(allData));
}); I am just using <!-- ko with: $data.menu --> as of now, to check for the 3rd level menu.

Comment: Reading your question a little closer, I recommend @PW Kad's answer.